How to configure the implementation under Ubuntu 22.04 cgroup v2 for restricting CPU usage for user accounts?
How to configure the implementation under Ubuntu 22.04 cgroup v2
For example
One.
A user (all processes and subsequent processes), limited to 10% CPU usage
Two.
B user (all processes and subsequent processes), limited to 20% CPU usage
I have successfully configured in the environment of CentOS 7 cgroup v1 (cgconfig.conf and cgrules.conf),
But how to do it in the Ubuntu 22.04 cgroup v2 environment?

Why was this question cross-posted on Super User?

I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.
